# Android crash randomly after camera intent close

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I've a problem with my app. Sometimes the app crashes after taking picture from camera without any usefull stack. Here's a snap of my code
**PhotoTakeNew.java**( where i take my photos)

```
.........

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int sec = (int) (c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
String newPhotoFileName = "photo-" + sec + ".jpg";

File dir = new File(this.path);
if ( !dir.exists() ) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File(dir, newPhotoFileName);

Uri _uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
this.general.setNewPhotoUri(_uri);
this.general.setNewPhotoLocation(null);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _uri);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 542880);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, 0);
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
PhotoTakeNew.this.general.startActivityForResult(intent, 102);
```

SomeFragment.java ( where i consume the activity result)

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (requestCode == 102) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    File imgfile = new File(this.newPhotoUri.getPath());

                    if ( imgfile.exists() ) {

                        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(this.newPhotoUri.getPath());
                        String rotation = ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
                        int orientation = Integer.valueOf(rotation);
                        //int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                        switch(orientation) {
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                LdpUtility.RotateBitmap(this.newPhotoUri.getPath(),90, context);
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                LdpUtility.RotateBitmap(this.newPhotoUri.getPath(),180, context);
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                LdpUtility.RotateBitmap(this.newPhotoUri.getPath(),270, context);
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                                //LdpUtility.RotateBitmap(this.newPhotoUri.getPath(),90);
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                                break;
                            default:
                                Log.w("Rotation undefined");
                        }

                        String wkt = null;
                        Double angle = null;
                        if ( newPhotoLocation != null ) {
                            wkt = "POINT(" + newPhotoLocation.getLongitude() + " " + newPhotoLocation.getLatitude() + ")";
                        }
                        if ( newPhotoLocation != null && newPhotoElementLong != null && newPhotoElementLat != null ) { 
                            angle = Geom.Tool(newPhotoLocation.getLongitude(), newPhotoLocation.getLatitude(), newPhotoElementLong, newPhotoElementLat);
                        }

                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        long sec = c.getTimeInMillis();
                        Photo img = new Photo(getActivity(),DataSource.DATASOURCE);
                        img.setValue(Photo.FILENAME, newPhotoUri.getPath());
                        img.setValue(Photo.DATA, String.valueOf(sec));
                        if ( wkt != null )
                            img.setValue(Photo.GEOMETRY, wkt);
                        if ( angolo != null )
                            img.setValue(Photo.ANGLE, String.valueOf(angle));
                        
                        this.element_photos.add(img);
                        
                        this.setUnsaved();
                        this.checkSavedStatus();
                        this.updatePhotoList();
                        this.updateInfoDetails();

                    }
                    
                }
            }
```

What happen is that sometimes( very very randomly) my app crashes after i tap the confirm button in camera activity, after a second or two it return on the previous activity with message:

```
Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!
```

I don't recycle any bitmap and the crash occurs also if i write a very simple onactivityresult like

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (requestCode == 102) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                    Log.d(" onActivityResult ! ");
                    
                }
                    
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**:
This is the entire logcat

```
/? A/Bitmap: Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!
/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 1859 (.android.myapp), pid 1859 (.android.myapp)

/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_phone_x86/generic_x86:9/PSR1.180720.012/4923214:userdebug/test-keys'
/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
/? A/DEBUG: pid: 1859, tid: 1859, name: .android.myapp  >>> it.myapp.android.myapp <<<
/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!'
/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00000743  ecx 00000743  edx 00000006
/? A/DEBUG:     edi 00000743  esi ff953f4c
/? A/DEBUG:     ebp ff953f18  esp ff953ea8  eip ee217b59
 3366-3420/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3885a80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe3883920)
 /? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
 /? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000b59  [vdso:ee217000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0001fdf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00022ed3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00006c84  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+292)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000fdbc9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::bitmap::toBitmap(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+89)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000fbdcb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::CanvasJNI::drawBitmapMatrix(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, _jobject*, long long, long long)+43)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 003ffab2  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ca000) (android.view.RecordingCanvas.nDrawBitmapMatrix+226)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00075ca7  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap+167)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00039cfc  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay.Overlay.draw+140)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00099a88  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView.onDraw+264)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 005bcb1e  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+1374)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 005e2da1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14369)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00456ddc  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/it.myapp.android.myapp-e9raEkSRseaAF79WDRnltg==/base.apk (deleted) (it.myapp.android.myapp.map.myappMapView.onDraw)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 000291f2  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+322)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 0001722b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+827)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 00024019  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+1321)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 000946b5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+69)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 00077c9b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1595)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 00017176  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+646)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 00024019  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+1321)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 000946b5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+69)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 00077c9b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1595)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 00017176  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+646)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 00024019  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+1321)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 000946b5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+69)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 00077c9b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1595)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 00029208  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+344)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 005bcb1e  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+1374)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 005e2da1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14369)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 00237a60  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/it.myapp.android.myapp-e9raEkSRseaAF79WDRnltg==/base.apk (deleted) (androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.draw)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 0001722b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+827)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 00024019  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+1321)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 000946b5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+69)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #49 pc 00077c9b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1595)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #50 pc 00017176  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+646)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #51 pc 00024019  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+1321)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #52 pc 000946b5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+69)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #53 pc 00077c9b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1595)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #54 pc 00029208  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+344)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #55 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #56 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #57 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #58 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #59 pc 005bcb1e  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+1374)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #60 pc 005e2da1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14369)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #61 pc 0120a138  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #62 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #63 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #64 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #65 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #66 pc 0001722b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+827)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #67 pc 00024019  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+1321)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #68 pc 000946b5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+69)
/? A/DEBUG:     #69 pc 00077c9b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1595)
/? A/DEBUG:     #70 pc 00029208  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+344)
/? A/DEBUG:     #71 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
/? A/DEBUG:     #72 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
/? A/DEBUG:     #73 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
/? A/DEBUG:     #74 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
/? A/DEBUG:     #75 pc 005bcb1e  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+1374)
/? A/DEBUG:     #76 pc 005e2da1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14369)
/? A/DEBUG:     #77 pc 00c1015e  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw)
/? A/DEBUG:     #78 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
/? A/DEBUG:     #79 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
/? A/DEBUG:     #80 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
/? A/DEBUG:     #81 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
/? A/DEBUG:     #82 pc 0001722b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+827)
/? A/DEBUG:     #83 pc 0005207b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList+107)
/? A/DEBUG:     #84 pc 0000e117  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList+87)
/? A/DEBUG:     #85 pc 00096886  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw+134)
/? A/DEBUG:     #86 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
/? A/DEBUG:     #87 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
/? A/DEBUG:     #88 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
/? A/DEBUG:     #89 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
/? A/DEBUG:     #90 pc 005bfbf2  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+706)
/? A/DEBUG:     #91 pc 005e6aa1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29985)
/? A/DEBUG:     #92 pc 00d22a06  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw+800)
/? A/DEBUG:     #93 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
/? A/DEBUG:     #94 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
/? A/DEBUG:     #95 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
/? A/DEBUG:     #96 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
/? A/DEBUG:     #97 pc 0000d945  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw+405)
/? A/DEBUG:     #98 pc 000379d9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals+14889)
/? A/DEBUG:     #99 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
/? A/DEBUG:     #100 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
/? A/DEBUG:     #101 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
/? A/DEBUG:     #102 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
/? A/DEBUG:     #103 pc 005bda66  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+342)
/? A/DEBUG:     #104 pc 005e2e21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14497)
/? A/DEBUG:     #105 pc 00b7aaa4  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal+62)
/? A/DEBUG:     #106 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
/? A/DEBUG:     #107 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
/? A/DEBUG:     #108 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
/? A/DEBUG:     #109 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
/? A/DEBUG:     #110 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
/? A/DEBUG:     #111 pc 00b77f38  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run+4)
/? A/DEBUG:     #112 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
/? A/DEBUG:     #113 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
/? A/DEBUG:     #114 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
/? A/DEBUG:     #115 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
/? A/DEBUG:     #116 pc 0002bc50  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run+224)
/? A/DEBUG:     #117 pc 000195fd  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks+669)
/? A/DEBUG:     #118 pc 0001bb79  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer.doFrame+1289)
/? A/DEBUG:     #119 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
/? A/DEBUG:     #120 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
/? A/DEBUG:     #121 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
/? A/DEBUG:     #122 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
/? A/DEBUG:     #123 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
/? A/DEBUG:     #124 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #125 pc 00b5e45a  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run+18)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #126 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #127 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #128 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #129 pc 005bd574  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1444)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #130 pc 005e2f21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14753)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #131 pc 00c45f9e  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Handler.handleCallback+4)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #132 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #133 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #134 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #135 pc 005bdc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #136 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #137 pc 00ae3940  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+8)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #138 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #139 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #140 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #141 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #142 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #143 pc 00aeaa50  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Looper.loop+404)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #144 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #145 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #146 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #147 pc 005bdc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #148 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #149 pc 00384ca2  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.main+214)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #150 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #151 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #152 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #153 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #154 pc 005f0d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #155 pc 000a30df  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #156 pc 004d3349  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+89)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #157 pc 004d502e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+1422)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #158 pc 00449783  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+83)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #159 pc 0011d778  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x114000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+168)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #160 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #161 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #162 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #163 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #164 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #165 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #166 pc 00c0b7ca  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
 /? A/DEBUG:     #167 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2020-11-30 11:41:25.722 /? A/DEBUG:     #168 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
2020-11-30 11:41:25.722 /? A/DEBUG:     #169 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
2020-11-30 11:41:25.722 /? A/DEBUG:     #170 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
2020-11-30 11:41:25.722 /? A/DEBUG:     #171 pc 00badc3c  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ca000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+3100)
2020-11-30 11:41:25.722 /? A/DEBUG:     #172 pc 005f0d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
2020-11-30 11:41:25.722 /? A/DEBUG:     #173 pc 000a30df  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
2020-11-30 11:41:25.722 /? A/DEBUG:     #174 pc 004d3349  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous ...
(cropped due to length)
```

Comment: Please add the entire error message from logcat.

Comment: I've added the entire error message. Hope you can help me, thanks very much

Comment: Your app should be crashing on Android 7.0 and higher with a `FileUriExposedException`. Do not use `Uri.fromFile()`. Set up `FileProvider` and use it.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your commetn. I've replaced Uri.fromFile with the fileProvider but the problem is still there. After taking some photo ( one,two, ten, twenty or more randomly) the app still crash